# How to use Ruby's write_nonblock / read_nonblock with servers/clients?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, iostream, send, nonblocking

I'm trying to use Ruby with servers.  I'm getting an enter or a string from players so that the server will play a hand of war (the card game).

What's really frustrating is I'm using read and write_nonblock, and I keep running into errors that I don't know why they come up and thus have no idea how to resolve them.

```
Errno::EAGAIN: Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block #etc. etc.
```

SO...how do I properly use read and write non_block to send and receive data (so I can trigger events) on servers and clients?  (I'm a new programmer, so the simpler the explanation the better.)

Comment: just trap `Errno::EAGAIN` exception

Comment: Thanks.  But, being pretty amateur, would you explain how to do that/how that would help?  And I'm still not sure how to actually *properly use* the non_block methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pair of methods `#write(read)_nonblock` are need in order to do some proceeds on a code you need in case when data isn't ready to be sent or be received. The `ruby` [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock) say the following on the methods:

> If the exception is `Errno::EWOULDBLOCK` or `Errno::AGAIN`, it is extended by IO::WaitReadable. So IO::WaitReadable can be used to rescue the exceptions for retrying read_nonblock.

Just trap `Errno::EAGAIN` exception.

**Note** that `retry` keyword make the method like usual `#write(read)`:

```
begin
   io.write_nonblock
rescue Errno::EAGAIN
   retry # or do something else
end
```